# How to make a dictionary using bat

Tags: batch-file

I have a given file. I need to create a folder that has 27 files. The first file contains alphabetically ordered and unique words from the given file that start with a, the second that starts with b, and so on.

The 27th file contains the words that start with other characters. I managed to do my dictionary using `awk`, but i have to do it in `bat` and it's causing me a lot of problems.

Comment: How are the words listed in your file? One per line? If so, then that's quite easy, if not it may be impossible, as batch files don't support unbounded tokenisation.

Comment: i can have any number of words per line.i have to put one word per line in those 27 files.i can use a c program too.but it still sounds very complicated.

Comment: can you help assuming that there only one word per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you had NOT requested us to *explain* the Batch file, right? :-)

```
@echo off
md folder
for /F "delims=" %%a in (theFile.txt) do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      set word[%%b]=1
   )
)
for %%a in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
   (for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in ('set word[%%a') do (
       echo %%b
       set word[%%b]=
   )) > folder\%%a.txt 2>NUL
)
(for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in ('set word[') do (
   echo %%b
   set word[%%b]=
)) > folder\other.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

well technically I can think of many different ways you can do this but I would recommend doing something like this:

```
@echo off
title dictionary
color 0a

echo enter the word you want for its definition.
echo.
set/p A=
if %A%==game GOTO game
ELSE
goto end
:end
Exit

:game
cls
echo.
echo game:a competitive activity involving skill, chance, or endurance on the part of two or more 
echo persons who play according to a set of rules, usually for their own amusement or for that of echo spectators.
echo.
pause
:end
Exit
```

And I'm just saying that this advice is coming from a teen!

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable. The trick is to start each line with 4 spaces.